# Delphi correct signature for LowLevelKeyboardProc()

Tags: delphi, hook, keyboard-events

I´m writing a global keyboard hook in Delphi 2007 and Windows 10. I´ve found different signatures for a Delphi LowLevelKeyboardProc callback. Someones like this and windows documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85))
[LowLevelKeyboardProc() never is executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57260687/lowlevelkeyboardproc-never-is-executed)
prompt that *lparam* is a pointer to a *TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* record.
Other ones however (http://www.delphifaq.com/faq/delphi_windows_API/f512.shtml and https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/en/showcode.php?id=1722), show

```
function KeyHookFunc(Code, VirtualKey, KeyStroke: Integer): LRESULT; stdcall;
```

completely ignoring the *TKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT* record pointer.
Which one is correct?
I'm guessing the first one is the correct one but I need to be sure. I´ve been using such signature but when I call another *Function* in the same unit (and DLL) passing *lParam* it causes Access Violation when accessing it. All functions and procedures within the DLL use *stdcall*

Comment: The MS link is correct. It's difficult to say why your code isn't working, because we can't see your code from here. The Delphi definition can be found in Windows.pas: `TFNHookProc = function (code: Integer; wparam: WPARAM; lparam: LPARAM): LRESULT stdcall;`

Answer (score 1):

All of the callback declarations are correct, although the latter two links do not give examples of `LowLevelKeyboardProc` but [`KeyboardProc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/keyboardproc). IOW, they are not low level keyboard hooks.

Note the latter two wouldn't work in 64 bits due to Integer usage instead of WPARAM, LPARAM and LRESULT.

Comment: A little confused here. What's the difference between LowLevelKeyboardProc and KeyboardProc? I guess that the access violation occurs due to handling `LowLevelKeyboardProc` as a `KeyboardProc:  
  
`   hGlobalKeyHook := `SetWindowsHookEx(**WH_KEYBOARD**,@LowLevelKeyboardProc,HInstance,0);`
and as far as I´ve seen they receive a different set of arguments.

Comment: Low level hooks are triggered when they are generated, high level hooks are triggered when a process is about to retrieve the input event message from its message queue. Consequently implementations are not alike. I'm sure docs would explain better than me. Indeed you can't pass the address of a low level callback procedure for a KeyboardProc, that would definitely crash.